# Select entity connection string at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an application that connects to a MYSQL database. I use Entity Framework to do all the job. 
Now When I first Installed, I set up entity, and resulted in a connection string like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="networkingEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string="server=localhost;user id=root;password=lucian;persist security info=True;database=networking"" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Now, my application has 2 users: an admin and a student.

Form1 => updates information from database and from server

Login form=> the users authentificate

MainForm => where all the action takes part. If the admin is logged in he can modify contents in the database

The database:
has 2 users: root and lucian.

"lucian" is a limited user...

Now, my problem is:

**How can I add a second connection string to the already existing one, and select that one at runtime? I mean, when Form1 is running, put the thread to sleep, select the second connections string and then, go to Login form, login as admin and make the cnahge sin the database?**

And how can I get tho login information from the connection string, from an external file?

Comment: Use [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb739017.aspx) to choose by name. Or if you use EF5, [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467(v=vs.103).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you have used either EF DB first or model first as a result of which the connection string was added to the app.config by Entity Framework. If the second connection string should point to the same database, add a new DataModel to your project and point it to the database of your choice and generate a model from it after which, EF makes the connection string for you.

To target the second connection string.

```
// by name attribute from the app.config/web.config
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["networkingEntities"].ConnectionString; connection string.
// or select by index.
var index = 0;
var adminConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConntectionString[++index];
var userConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString[index];
```

Edit to your answer.
Hi, because I too am interested in this topic I did a quick google and found this one:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.protectsection.aspx
It seems .NET has a few handy build in mechanism for us available. Tho I am also new to the topic I have no readily answer as to how it is used. GLHF

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I have solved:
**1.** Modified the App.config like:

```
 <connectionstrings configsource="DatabaseConnectionDetails.config" />;
```

and this is DatabaseConnectionDetails.config:

```
<connectionstrings>
    <add name="networkingEntities" connectionstring="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=lucian;password=lucian;persist security info=True;database=networking&quot;" providername="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="networkingEntitiesAdmin" connectionstring="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=lucian;persist security info=True;database=networking&quot;" providername="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionstrings>
```

**2.**Added a contructor with string parameter to Model1.Context.tt template:

```
 public <#=code.Escape(container)#>(string myString)
        : base(myString)
    {
<#
if (!loader.IsLazyLoadingEnabled(container))
{
#>
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
<#
}
#>
    }
```

**3.**get the connection string like this:

```
string  str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["networkingEntitiesAdmin"].ConnectionString;
```

**4.**And whenever I want to use the context , I use(for example):

```
networkingEntities net=new networkingEntities(str);


public List<utilizator> ListaUtilizatori()
        {

            var query = from u in net.utilizator
                        select u;
            List<utilizator> users = new List<utilizator>();
            try
            {
                users = query.ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            return users;
        }
```

Now, I still have to discover how I encrypt the config files....
Thank you all for help...